# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.CommandType'

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

I was looking at a web tutorial and the instructor was speaking in language I do not understand and the video was not showing complete length. Can anyone advise me how the line should look like...

```
 private void Insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); // this is good
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    // this is good
   cmd.CommandType = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, 
   StudentDOB) Values('" + StudIDTxt.Text + "','" + StudNameTxt.Text + "','" + 
   StudCNCITxt.Text + "','" + StudDOBTxt.Text +")"; *// Need help here pls*
   cmd.Connection=myCon;   
   myCon.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   myCon.Close();
 }
```

I am developing in VS 2010 C#. Using Access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use always *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. Your code is open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacs.

In your query, you should use `CommandText` property, not `CommandType`

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, 
   StudentDOB) Values(@StudIDTxt, @StudNameTxt, @StudCNCITxt, @StudDOBTxt)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudIDTxt", StudIDTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudNameTxt", StudNameTxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudCNCITxt", StudCNCITxt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudDOBTxtl", StudDOBTxt.Text);
```

Comment: Rather than pointing out what is wrong, show him a correct version.

Comment: Now It is Better Answer..+1 for you @Soner Gönül

Comment: +1 from me too, if I were to understand someone who downvoted, I'd say that it took you few edits to finally deliver a correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Your:

```
cmd.CommandType = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, 
   StudentDOB) Values('" + StudIDTxt.Text + "','" + StudNameTxt.Text + "','" + 
   StudCNCITxt.Text + "','" + StudDOBTxt.Text +")";
```

should be

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, 
   StudentDOB) Values('" + StudIDTxt.Text + "','" + StudNameTxt.Text + "','" + 
   StudCNCITxt.Text + "','" + StudDOBTxt.Text +"')";
```

You made a typo.

Also, single quote was missing - (`StudDOBTxt.Text +")"`) should have been `StudDOBTxt.Text +"')"` - that would cause syntax error on the SQL server side.

As for parametrized form of your query (form that is safe from SQL injection attack), it would have to use question marks instead of named parameters (that's how it works in ODBC when command type is text), it would be something like this:

```
   cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, StudentDOB) 
                        Values(?,?,?,?)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p1", StudIDTxt.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p2", StudNameTxt.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p3", StudCNCITxt.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("p4", StudDOBTxt.Text));
```

Comment: Oh yes I have seen it now. Thank you so much, Ivan

Comment: @bucketblast You're welcome :) As others noted, you should consider using parametrized queries, they prevent SQL injections (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters.aspx).

Comment: Is that why I am recieving an error "Syntax error in string in query expression ''05/51/2013)'."?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); // this is good
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    // this is good
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNCI, 
    StudentDOB) Values('" + StudIDTxt.Text + "','" + StudNameTxt.Text + "','" + 
    StudCNCITxt.Text + "','" + StudDOBTxt.Text +")"; *// Need help here pls*
    cmd.Connection=myCon;   
    myCon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCon.Close();
  }
```

**It should be Command Text not Command type**